# How do i only get objects from the JSON and not the strings?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON, and I want to loop through it but when i loop through it, due to the strings present with it, the loop is failing. How do i just loop through the objects in the JSON ?

I just want to iterate through the objects within that JSON.

- I tried `if(json.length!=3)` but it fails when it hits the object because i think it cannot find a length for the object
- I also tried `json.hasOwnProperty("field_id")` which is also failing when i hit the string "and"
- I also tried `if(json.length=undefined)` which also fails because the length itself goes into undefined state

Here's my JSON:

```
[
    {
        "field_id": 122,
        "operator_id": "1",
        "where_flag": true
    "and",
    {
        "field_id": 128,
        "operator_id": "0",
        "where_flag": true
    },
    "and",
    {
        "field_id": 148,
        "operator_id": "1",
        "where_flag": true
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend filtering the items first and then, looping over the objects:

```
function isObject(value) {
  return typeof value === "object" && value !== null
}

array.filter(item => isObject(item)).forEach(...)
```

or just squeezing them in one loop (which I don't usually recommend):

```
array.forEach(item => {
  if(!isObject(item)) return;

  ...
})
```

Comment: Thank you for this.. let me try this out

Answer (score 1):

maybe this will work,

```js
let array = [
    {
        "field_id": 122,
        "operator_id": "1",
        "where_flag": true
    },
    "and",
    {
        "field_id": 128,
        "operator_id": "0",
        "where_flag": true
    },
    "and",
    {
        "field_id": 148,
        "operator_id": "1",
        "where_flag": true
    }
]

array.forEach((elem)=>{
    if(typeof(elem)=="object"){
        console.log(elem)
    }
})
```

Comment: This one works!

Comment: how do i just delete it completely and store it into a new JSON variable rather than just filter it ?

Comment: i dont know much about json, but i guess you are talking about this
`

let newArray = []

array.forEach((elem)=>{

    if(typeof(elem)=="object"){
        newArray.push(elem)
    }
})
newArray = JSON.stringify(newArray)
`